# 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'"

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have been using pandas for a while and it worked fine but out of nowhere, it decided to give me this error

> AttributeError("module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'")

Now I have spent many many hours trying to solve this issue viewing every StackOverflow forum but they don't help.

1. I know where both my cvs + python files are located.
2. My script is not called cvs.py or anything such.
3. My code can literally just be `'import pandas as pd' and I get the
   no attribute error.

I would appreciate if someone could spare the time + assist me in solving this problem.

Comment: Which pandas version are you using? I can correctly perform the `from pandas import read_csv` instruction and it is working fine with pandas 0.23.1 version

Comment: Try removing and reinstall pandas. `pip uninstall pandas` then `pip install pandas`

Comment: Execute the code line by line to see if you have error 1) `import pandas as pd`
2) `print(pd.read_csv)`

Comment: Sai Kumar I tried your solution and it worked. Thanks a lot bud. But why did I have to uninstall it in the first place?

Comment: You mention "CVS", a version control system, several times and the question is tagged to "CVS". Are you sure you mean "CVS" and not "CSV"? If not, please correct the question text and tags.

Comment: Pandas may be using the standard module `csv`. I suggest renaming your file `csv.py` to something that does not imitate any standard module.

Answer (score 3):

I've just been spinning my wheels on the same problem.

TL/DR: try renaming your python files

I think there must be a number of other naming conflicts besides some of the conceivably obvious ones like csv.py and pandas.py mentioned in other posts on the topic.

In my case, I had a single file called inspect.py. Running on the command line gave me the error, as did running `import pandas` from within a python3 shell, but only when launching the shell from the same directory as inspect.py. I renamed inspect.py, and now it works just fine!!

Comment: I had my file called pandas.py and it wouldn't work so I renamed it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it is probably cause of writing

dataframe = pd.read.csv("dataframe.csv")

instead of

dataframe = pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv")

that little "_" is the problem.

Hope this helps somebody else too.

Answer (score 1):

After spending 2 hours researching a solution to this question, running `pip uninstall pandas` and then `pip install pandas` in your terminal will work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Since I had this problem just now, and on the whole internet **no** answer covered my issue:

You may have pandas installed (Like I did), but in the wrong environment. Especially when you just start out in Python and use an IDE like PyCharm, you don't realise that you may create a new Environment (Called "pythonProject", "pythonProject1", pythonProject2",... by default), and installing a package *does not mean it is installed in all Environments*.

If you have AnacondaNavigator installed, you can easily look up which Environment has which packages.

---

This is a very cruel oversight, as PyCharm doesn't warn you of the misplaced package; it just looks up if it is *somewhere*; so you don't get the error at import.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem when I update my python packages using `conda update --all`.

The error:
`AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'`

I believe it is a pandas path problem.

The solution:

print(pd)
To see where are your pandas come from. I was getting
`<module 'pandas' (namespace)>`

Then I used to print(np), for example, to see where my numpy is, then I got
`<module 'numpy' from 'C:\\Users\\name\\Anaconda3\\envs\\eda_env\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>`

I used the same path to find my pandas path. I found out that the folder `lib` named `Lib` with an uppercase letter. I change it to lowercase lib, and it solves my problem.

Change `Lib` to `lib` or check a working module and make sure pandas have the same.